# Data passing using Intent between three classes

Tags: android, android-intent

Let I have three classes A, B, and C. A passes the variable 'name' to B using 'intend' as

```
Intent intend = new Intent(ViewData.this, MainActivity.class);
intend.putExtra("name1", name);
ViewData.this.startActivity(intend);
```

B receives 'name' as

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uname = intent.getStringExtra("name1");
```

Then B sends the variable 'name' to C and changes the contents to "Ramesh".
C sends the updated variable 'name' back.

So the value of the variable in Class B 'name' must be "Ramesh".
But the 'name' is showing as null.

Why the variable is showing null???
To get the variable 'name' as "Ramesh", What steps to be taken???

Comment: B receives 'name' in oncreate?

Comment: Does B actually receive `name1`? Also, what is `name` in A? Is it a string or a `Uname` object?

Comment: @rafid059 mysteries of life

Comment: name1 is astring.

Comment: B does not receive name back from C...

Comment: you can also use this library with annotations which makes it easier: https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First send the the data from A to B like this

```
 Intent intend = new Intent(ViewData.this, MainActivity.class);
 intend.putExtra("name1", name);
 startActivity(intend);
```

And recieve in B like this

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  Uname = intent.getStringExtra("name1");
```

Pass again to C

```
 Intent intend = new Intent(this,"Your c class name.class");
 intend.putExtra("name1", Uname);
 startActivity(intend);
```

receive again at Class c

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 Uname = intent.getStringExtra("name1");
```

Change the value or whatever you have to do..then do this at C

```
  Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
  returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);//your changed value here
  setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
  finish();
```

And on Class b do this:

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        String result=data.getStringExtra("result");

        //you will get the changed data here
      }
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
          //Write your code if there's no result
     }
  }
  }//onActivityResult
```